# Increase hover detection radius

Tags: css

I've tried `border-radius; xx` on both `#my-element` and `a:hover#my-element`, but it's not working.

What is the proper way to set the radius of hover detection in css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hover event will be triggered as soon as your mouse enters within the bounds of your element.

`border-radius` does not change the radius of the hoverable zone of your element but changes the rounded effect of the *default* square corners of your element.

If you want to enhance the coverable zone of your element I suggest you put it inside a bigger element with a size you please and then you detect the *hover* event of this element.

Of course because CSS is a wonderful tool you can change the style of an element within an hovered element using the following selector:

```
#elementBIG:hover #originalElement {...}
```

The HTML of this example then becomes:

```
<div id="elementBIG">
    <div id="originalElement"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want it like this?

By using pseudo it doesn't flip back and forth when the mouse gets outside the border by the hover effect.

Also with the pseudo you keep the original elements size, you don't need extra element and you can easily make the hover area bigger.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  top: -20%;
  left: -20%;
  width: 140%;
  height: 140%;
}

div:hover {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>HOVER ME</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to wrap the targeted element in a dynamically sized div with padding set to the amount of hover MOE (margin of error) you are trying to achieve- then target the div ID for hover? - sort of hacky but not sure of how else you could achieve this effect.